# Tefillin & Shabbos for a giyur lchumra?

Tags: shabbat, conversion-to-judaism, tefilin

Should someone’s whose yiddishkeit is questionable wear tefillin and keep Shabbos?

Should someone who’s in the process of conversion do so as well?

Comment: Excellent questions, @Yes! They are, however, best posed to your rabbi.

Comment: There are different opinions on this. The London Beis Din has its candidates keep all mitzvos.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: There are a lot of shades of gray in "questionable"; a beis din must be consulted.

Comment: @JamesRead I assume the London Beis Din has a process, as do most reputable Batei Din. You don't just start wearing tefillin on day one; you wait until they tell you you are ready.